# The problem with relative coordinates in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, coordinates

AFAIK, in latest versions of `pgfplots` default coordinates are axis coordinates, so `axis cs` is no longer required.  However, there is still problem with **relative** coordinates.  See the example below

```
\documentclass[10pt,convert={convertexe=magick,density=1000,outext=.png}]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=10,ymin=-10,ymax=10]

\draw[black] (3,-4) -- ++(axis direction cs:6,0);
\draw[black] (3,-5) -- ++(6,-10);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

So in order to keep line horizontal, without using `axis direction cs`, one has to add *y0*, where *y0* is minimum *y* value in the plot.

Is this a bug or a feature?  I lost several hours debugging this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not suppose to be able to make relative coordinates work without `axis direction cs`. So it is not a bug -and also not a feature.

Page 357 in the manual.

> The result of **axis cs** is always an absolute position inside of an
> axis. This means, in particular, that adding two points has unexpected
> effects: the expression (0,0) ++ (1,0) is not necessarily the same as
> (1,0). The background for such unexpected effects is that pgfplots
> applies a shifted linear transformation which moves the origin in
> order to support its high accuracy and high data range (compare the
> documentation of disabledatascaling). In order to express relative
> positions (or lengths), you need to use **axis direction cs**.
>
> **Coordinate system axis direction cs**
>
> While **axis cs** allows to supply
> absolute positions, **axis direction cs** supplies directions. It allows
> to express relative positions, including lengths and dimensions, by
> means of axis coordinates. As noted in the documentation for axis cs,
> adding two coordinates by means of the TikZ ++ operator may have
> unexpected effects. The correct way for ++ operations is axis
> direction cs:

Comment: What I find confusing is that you can get correct absolute positions without `axis cs` but not get correct relative positions without `axis direction cs`.

Comment: You can NOT get absolute positions without `axis cs`.  `axis cs` IS required. The thing is that it is the default coordinate system since PGFPlots 1.11, so you no longer need to write it explicitly. See also edit, where I have added extra info from the manual.

Comment: Thanks, for consistency I decided to add `axis cs` to all absolute positions too.  However, this does not work in this case `(0,-10 -| a)`.  `(axis cs:0,-10 -| a)` returns error.  Do you perhaps know how to add  `axis cs` in this case?

Comment: `({axis cs:0,-10} -| a)`. You do not need and are also not advised to use `axis cs` explicitly when you correctly set `compat`. -just as you in plain TikZ also do not use  `canvas cs:` explicitly. Please accept the answer.